# Formula for a number sieries

Tags: sequences-and-series

What could possibly be the formula or the pattern for the following series of numbers:
1, 8, 27, 64, 125, 216,...

Thanks!

Comment: third degrees...

Comment: 1^3, 2^3, 3^3, 4^3, 5^3, ... n^3

Comment: Oh man, you're right! I couldn't see it, thanks!

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2C+8%2C+27%2C+64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Among other alternatives, this could be described as nth term = $n^3$.

Other less obvious candidates would be things like nth term = $n^3 + (n-1)(n-2)(n-3)(n-4)(n-5)(n-6)f(n)$ for f(n) any function of n.